# Pulling the postcode area from the full postcode

Tags: mariadb, query

If I have a Postcode `EH1 2GB` I am looking for a function which will pull only the EH

Ideally this would work for postcodes which may only contain 1 leading letter such as `G2 1AB` and 2 numbers after the leading letters such as EH54 1BD and G25 2RD

I have tried using

I have tried pulling pulling the whole postcode and then using javascript (`const extractPostalArea = (postalCode) => postalCode.match(/^[A-Z]+/)?.[0] ?? null;`) to further separate the Postcode, however this is causing more issues than it is solving.

Is there a way to pull the postcode that would give a result similar to the below table...

| Postcode | PostalArea |
| --- | --- |
| B2 1GH | B |
| EH2 4ED | EH |
| SL4 5FR | SL |
| E2W 4ST | E |

Any help would be much appreciated

I am using MariaDB

Comment: I have been using `SELECT Company, Address, Town, Postcode From CollectionAddress` which has been working fine. When I add `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Postcode,'[A-Z]+') AS PostalArea` to make `SELECT Company, Address, Town, Postcode, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Postcode,'[A-Z]+') AS PostalArea From CollectionAddress` it tells me that my query is syntactically wrong

Comment: Please provide the error message -- "near" tells us _exactly_ where to look.

Comment: @RickJames I got home and retyped it out and it seems to be working now

Comment: @PaulMcF87 Are you running the same version of MariaDB at home and wherever it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the same regex in MariaDB as you did in the JavaScript by using the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_substr/) function, like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Postcode, '^[A-Z]+') AS PostalArea From CollectionAddress
```

The `^` ensures that the one-or-more [A-Z] has to be at the start of the string.